# Unwanted space between . ("dot") and Y

Tags: spacing

I see that LaTeX does not eliminate the space before Y:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
e-mail: Kennedi.Yaccarino@somewhere.com
\end{document}
```

After searching I found a possible way to fix this is to add the following code just before Y:

```
.\kern-.15em
```

But I was surprised that LaTeX does not handle this by default. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I removed the thanks (which are implied) and the signature, since your name already appears in the question. I'm not sure there's a space to be removed.

Comment: There is no surprise here you wouldn't want TeX to not leave a space after the end of a sentence. Not any easy problem to automate see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation

Comment: @Yiannis: Space after sentence is Ok. In my case there is no space after period, so TeX understands that it is not end of sentence. There seems to be general problem with space before Y, you get similar results if you use any character before it.

Comment: inter-letter kerning is a property of the font in use, not of TeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is just kerning between the character `.` and `Y` not being set appropriately.  This is more or less difficult to "fix" depending on which TeX engine you're using.  For example, with luatex you can do this somewhat automatically:

[Fixing fonts with LuaTeX feature files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142605/fixing-fonts-with-luatex-feature-files)

Other fonts have better kerning by default and so this doesn't appear.  For example the Libertine fonts don't suffer from this artifact, while Pagella and Computer Modern both do.

Comment: I think the kerning *is* set appropriately. Kerning between characters is supposed to make words look good, but there are few words that have an uppercase letter in the middle, and therefore few fonts that provide much kerning befor an uppercase letter. There are even fewer words with a dot in the middle. Code, logos and special technical combinations are best left to the user to deal with. BTW, Libertine (at least in the type1 version I have) suffers from too much space in the combination `Y.`, which is a more serious problem.