# Accessing Junicode ligatures

Tags: ligatures

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{junicode}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=Discretionary]{junicode}

\begin{document}
fifty
nifty
activity
\end{document}
```

This will produce `fty` ligatures, but not a `ty` lig. in the last word.

[image]

Commenting out to use ‘discretionary’ ligatures will enable `ty` but disable `fty`.  How can I enable both?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you can get only what the font provides. If it has bad tables, you can possibly fix them with Fontforge.

Comment: @egreg, or with a feature file?

Comment: With LuaTeX, perhaps.

Comment: Solved it from this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142605/fixing-fonts-with-luatex-feature-files#142664 --, adding a feature file with
feature liga {
 sub t y by t_y;
} liga;

Comment: You may add a self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a feature file to add the ty (and other desired) ligatures to the liga feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{junicode.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature liga {
    sub t y by t_y;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\setmainfont[FeatureFile={junicode.fea}]{junicode}

\begin{document}
fifty
nifty
activity
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ummm, this code does *not* provide an answer to the issue you raised in the posting. The `fty` ligature is in the "Common" group of ligatures, and it gets employed whether or not the feature file is loaded -- as long as "Discretionary" ligatures aren't loaded as well. If the "Discretionary" (aka "Rare") group of ligatures is loaded, the feature file approach (with `sub f t y by f_t_y` in the "liga" feature) does *not* work, and the `ty` ligature is employed -- whether or not the feature file is loaded. Please provide an approach that solves the issue raised in the posting itself.

Comment: @Mico, the question was how to enable both ligatures at the same time, and that q. has been answered. An alternative is probably to add f_t_y to the dlig feature.

Comment: I had read your original question as asking how to (re)enable the `fty` ligature *if* the Discretionary/Rare group of ligatures is activated. It would be helpful if your answer showed explicitly how this might be accomplished via a feature file approach. If, on the other hand, your question was *not* about discretionary ligatures, it might be helpful if you edited your posting to clarify the posting's objective.

Comment: @Mico, frankly I think I indicated with sufficient clarity that I was interested in the ligatures and not the ligature groups. The question was ‘how could I enable both [ligatures]’. If you disagree you are welcome to edit the question or give a better answer.